# DOCTYPE transitional in HTML

Tags: html

I was reading a book about HTML and there is a paragraph I wasn't able to understand:

> If you have use lots of legacy stuff from back in the 2.0 and 3.2 days
>   of HTML. Then use HTML 4.01  Transitional  DOCTYPE, which allows you
>   to validate your pages but still permit some of legacy HTML. So, that
>   you don’t have to  rework all your HTML to get it to validate.

My question is What is the meaning of the above paragraph and

What’s the difference between Transitional and Strict DOCTYPE of HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Strict is closer to the designers' ideal for HTML 4. Transitional includes additional obsolete stuff that has been mostly replaced by CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to keep in mind, in addition to the doctypes' intrinsic differences, is that the HTML 4 *Transitional* doctype is the only modern (by that, I mean HTML versions 4 and up) doctype that triggers quirks mode <sup>1</sup> (this is bad!); all others trigger standards mode rendering.

<sup>1</sup> See the [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Also, please note that it's a little more complicated; the transitional doctype triggers quirks mode when it has no system identifier, and standards mode when it does. You really should be using HTML 4.01 strict, or better still, HTML 5.

Comment: If you use the Transitional Doctype as written in the HTML specification then you will **not** trigger Quirks mode. You only get Quirks mode if you omit the system identifier from it (i.e. the URI).

Comment: I wonder, is it illegal behaviour to omit the system identifier?

Comment: It is valid to omit it, but the specification isn't clear on if it is a case of "This is the Doctype you will use" or "This is the Doctype, you may modify it as per the SGML specification".

Answer (score 0):

In STRICT doctype you have to refer to and only to the HTML standard you define. Older rules are deprecated and thus validation will fail if they are broken.

If you have old HTML formatted documents and do not want to change them to conform to the new rules, then you are allowed to use to some extend both new and old rules, using transitional HTML.

Comment: There are non-deprecated things that don't appear in Strict. There are things which are new for HTML 4 in Transitional but not in Strict.

Answer (score 0):

The doctype declaration refers to a Document Type Definition (DTD). The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

Please go through these sites to educate yourself - 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp, http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html, http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: Don't use the W3Schools article, it has many errors. It has only **two** paragraphs that I can't see an error in … and one of those is just an instruction to look on a different page.

Comment: DTDs only specify some of the rules, and no browser uses the DTD to determine how to render content (some will use the Doctype to switch rendering modes, but that isn't what the Doctype should be used for, and it isn't based on the DTD — it just treats the Doctype as a magic string).

Comment: May I know what is the use of this strings and why they added?